# SQLite Date index shows no performance improvement

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

My SQLite database has over 500,000 rows. Being new I have just started using additional indexes in my VB.net application with some startling speed improvements :).

These improvements are not replicated when I index the Date column of my table. I am going to include some code snippets details below and would appreciate any input regarding what I may be doing wrong.

```
    'When creating the date column in DB (amongst others) 
oMainQueryR.CommandText += "RDate DATE, "

'creating index
oMainQueryR.CommandText = "Create INDEX main.iRDate ON DatabaseRows(RDate)"   
      oMainQueryR.ExecuteNonQuery()

'Storing the Data
.Parameters.Add(":Rdate", DbType.Date)
cmdSQLite.Parameters(":Rdate").Value = CDate(TextSplit(1)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")



'SQL Call to retrieve data
 oMainQueryR.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DatabaseRows " _
                            & "WHERE DATE([RDate]) BETWEEN DATE(:StartDate) AND DATE(:EndDate) " _
```

The Calls and everything is working OK and I get the correct functionality its just there is no improvement when I index the RDate column speed wise.

I should mention that the index appears to be created correctly

Would appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: This isn't a VB.Net issue. Also - 500K rows seems a bit excessive to be doing things in SQLite. I am assuming that you're using SQLite to avoid the overhead of a full database, which also may mean the hardware is not very good. Perhaps this is more of a disk reading issue at this point?

Comment: It is a VB.net issue in as much that I am using Vb .net to write the application, to apply the suggested improvements I had to change the data in the database once done the improvements were in the same staggering category as all the others. GREAT HELP thank you. 500K of rows gave me a days worth of data in 7sec using the old method now its almost instantaneous from that point of view I disagree that 500k rows is excessive for SQLite, at least Im ecstatic with the new performance especially given that I was happy with the old one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite does not use an index for this lookup because you are not looking up a column value but the result of a function call, and it is not the value `DATE(RDate)` that is stored in the index.

Drop the `DATE` function from your query; it does nothing in your query except preventing optimizations:

```sql
... WHERE RDate BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate
```

To check whether SQLite actually uses your index in a query, use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Please note `dd/MM/yyyy` is not one of SQLite's [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime); you must use `yyyy-MM-dd` for string comparisons to work correctly.

(For lookups like this, is does not matter much whether you store the date as a string or as a number.)

Comment: Thank you SOOOO for the help, changing the dates in the database to yyyy-MM-dd and removing the Date function from the call made the improvements that I was experiencing with the other indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Consider storing your date data within `INTEGER` (Date data type is not intrinsically supported by SQLite).

That would turn query into

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseRows WHERE RDate BETWEEN (:StartDate) AND (:EndDate);
```

which will avoid big amounts of `DATE` function calls.

Indeed, your `DATE` function call totally disables `INDEX` improvement.

Also, `INTEGER` comparison is way much faster then `TEXT` comparison.