# How can I speed this SQL statement up with an index in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT tag, count(tag) AS count, created_at 
FROM tags 
WHERE created_at >= strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now', '-1 days') 
GROUP BY tag 
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

I have the following index, but its still super slow:

`CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_tags_created_at__tag ON tags(created_at, tag)`

I'm getting a slow response here and wondering how I can speed this up with an index if possible.

Comment: You're facing a fundamental sorting problem. There are two columns you want to be sorted; the created_at, so you can quickly filter, and the tag so that you can quickly aggregate the data to generate your results. Assuming there are many fewer possible tags than created_at values, you should index by `tag, created_at` (a single compound index); so that you can quickly filter each tag's data (one tag at a time) by their created_at, and quickly aggregate too. Also, make certain that the created is a real date/time style data type and not a string type.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_ for a handy tool to suggest indexes to add.

Comment: it mentions an index I already have, but not the compound index.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create index based on `created_at` field and use your sql for query.

One time run query to setup index:

```
CREATE INDEX created_at_index 
ON tags(created_at);
```

this post have a good discussion how you can debug if your query is actually using the index or not by using `EXPLAIN` query:

[SQLite Date index shows no performance improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846044/sqlite-date-index-shows-no-performance-improvement)

https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: Should be `tag, created_at`, to accommodate the `GROUP BY tag`.